# .cmd vs .ps1 in Path

Tags: powershell, batch-file, path, scripting

I have added a folder to my Path that contains a `foo.cmd` batch file and `foo.ps1` powershell script. (The batch file is there to run the powershell script with a bypassed execution policy.)

When in powershell/command prompt I run

```
> foo
```

it runs `foo.ps1` in preference to `foo.cmd`, which is the opposite of what I want. Is there any way to get round this, without having to type `> foo.cmd`?

Comment: The environment variable `pathext` gives the sequence in which extensions will be examined.

Comment: @Magoo But that variable doesn't list `.PS1`.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers : doesn't on my system, either. Can't say for OP's system. Wonder what would happen if it was included in `pathext`.

Comment: @Magoo Nothing. I already tried. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Command precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_command_precedence?view=powershell-3.0) in PowerShell is defined like this:

> If you do not specify a path, PowerShell uses the following precedence order when it runs commands:
>
> 1. Alias
> 2. Function
> 3. Cmdlet
> 4. Native Windows commands
>
> Therefore, if you type "help", PowerShell first looks for an alias named "help", then a function named "Help", and finally a cmdlet named "Help". It runs the first "help" item that it finds.

Precedence of external ("native Windows") commands is then controlled by the `PATH` and `PATHEXT` environment variables. The former lists the directories Windows searches for external commands is the command wasn't invoked with a (relative or absolute) path, the latter lists extensions that Windows will auto-append if no match was found. For each environment variable the first match wins, meaning if you have a PATH listing `C:\foo;C:\bar` and have a folder structure like this:

```
C:
├─bar
│ └─a.exe
└─foo
  ├─a.cmd
  └─a.vbs
```

Windows will execute `C:\foo\a.cmd` when you invoke the command `a` (without path or extension), because `C:\foo` comes first in the `PATH` and `.cmd` comes before `.vbs` in the `PATHEXT` variable.

However, PowerShell scripts seem to rank somewhere between cmdlets and external commands as far as PowerShell is concerned, because their extension not listed in `$env:PATHEXT`, but you can't supersede builtin cmdlets with PowerShell scripts of the same name. I wasn't able to find documentation about this, though.

Bottom line: I think you'll either have to invoke the batch script with extension or rename the PowerShell script. The latter could be done by appending a fixed suffix to the basename of the file and then invoke it from the batch script like this:

```
@echo off
set "suffix=-bar"
powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -File "%~dpn0%suffix%.ps1"
```

Comment: "PowerShell scripts seem to rank somewhere between cmdlets and external commands as far as PowerShell is concerned …" Are you saying that PowerShell will invoke `foo.ps1` over `foo.cmd` if both are in the same directory on the path, even though `ps1` lexically comes after `cmd`? It's not clear that's what you're saying (because later in the sentence you compare precedence of PowerShell scripts to built-in cmdlets). In my testing it seems this seems to be the case, however. Any thoughts or references about this?